# Delphi : incorrect parameter message error with AdoQuery using SQL aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I use delphi XE5, I have a database with 7 tables, and my problem: I click on a button which runs this code:

```
dbgridappr2.Enabled:=false;
adoquery4.Parameters.Clear;
datasource6.DataSet:=adoquery4;
ADOQuery4:=TADOQuery.Create(Application);
adoquery4.Active:=False;
adoquery4.Connection:=ADOConnection1;
adoquery4.SQL.Clear;
adoquery4.SQL.Add('select SPEC.ISp AS ''Spécialité'',COUNT(APPR.NValAp) AS ''Nombre dApprentis de même Spécialité''  ');
adoquery4.SQL.Add('FROM APPR,SPEC ');
adoquery4.SQL.Add('where SPEC.CSp=APPR.CSp ');
adoquery4.SQL.Add('GROUP BY SPEC.ISp ');
adoquery4.SQL.Add('ORDER BY COUNT(APPR.NValAp) desc ');
ADOQuery4.Prepared := True;
ADOQuery4.ExecSQL;
//adoquery4.Open;
adoquery4.Active:=true;
dbgridappr2.Visible:=true;
dbgridappr2.DataSource:=datasource6;
dbgridappr2.Enabled:=true;
```

I have the result in a `DbGrid` but the message error show incorrect parameter ??

I changed the button code but I always get the same error message. I have 10 buttons that all run similar code with different `AdoQuery` and I have the result but I have always the same message error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted is an absolute mess. Here's why:

You clear the `adoquery4.Parameters` here, and assign `adoquery4` to `datasource6.DataSet`:

```
dbgridappr2.Enabled:=false;
adoquery4.Parameters.Clear;
datasource6.DataSet:=adoquery4;
```

You then immediately throw away the existing `adoquery4` (leaking memory in the process), and replace it with a new instance of `TADOQuery`:

```
ADOQuery4:=TADOQuery.Create(Application);
```

You then close the newly created `ADOQuery4` (which could not possibly be `Active` at this point), assign a connection (which would be fine), and clear the `SQL` (which could not possibly have any content here):

```
adoquery4.Active:=False;
adoquery4.Connection:=ADOConnection1;
adoquery4.SQL.Clear;
```

So far, about 90% of what you've done is meaningless.

Then you make the mistake of calling `ADOQuery4.ExecSQL;`, which is used to execute queries that return no rowset, like `INSERT`, `DELETE`, and so forth. You need to use `ADOQuery4.Open` or `ADOQuery4.Active := True` instead for a `SELECT`. This is the actual cause of the error you're getting; you're calling `ExecSQL` with an SQL statement that returns a rowset, and that's invalid.

Let's try again, and throw in a slight improvement in the SQL in the process. Ignore everything you've posted here, and start over:

```
ADOQuery4.DisableControls;
try
  // If the query is
  if ADOQuery4.Active then
    ADOQuery4.Close;

  ADOQuery4.Parameters.Clear;
  ADOQuery4.SQL.Clear;
  AdoQuery4.SQL.Add('select SPEC.ISp AS ''Spécialité'',');
  AdoQuery4.SQL.Add('COUNT(APPR.NValAp) AS ''Nombre dApprentis de même Spécialité''');
  AdoQuery4.SQL.Add('FROM APPR INNER JOIN SPEC');
  AdoQuery4.SQL.Add('ON SPEC.CSp = APPR.CSp');
  AdoQuery4.SQL.Add('GROUP BY SPEC.ISp ');
  AdoQuery4.SQL.Add('ORDER BY COUNT(APPR.NValAp) desc');
  ADOQuery4.Open;
finally
  ADOQuery4.EnableControls;
end;
```

(I don't know what all of the juggling of the `dbgridappr2.DataSource` is about, but unless you're changing the datasource from a different query none of that is necessary. The calls to `DisableControls` and `EnableControls` stops any UI components from being updated while the new query is executed.)

Comment: ça marche parfaitement ,, it's perfect thank you ,, and i used this method in all th button who have sql requet,, thank you ;) ken white